# Misleading migration reason in automated text box

Tags: bug, status-deferred, migration, close-reasons

Whenever we migrate a question to Stack Overflow now, the justification text is misleading the person who asked the question (and probably everyone else):

> This question was migrated to Stack Overflow because it can be answered by professional and enthusiast programmers.

[image]

This is just wrong. The question was closed, because it is a programming question that is **not related to WordPress**.

Most of our top users *are* "professional and enthusiast programmers", and WordPress related programming questions are very much welcome on our site. Hence our name: WordPress *Development*.

I haven't seen the close reasons for migrations to other sites yet. If the message above is an indicator for the quality of those text boxes, I have to ask that we moderators can edit them.

If that is not possible for some reason, the please fix at least the text above.

Comment: Yes. It comes across as: *This question was migrated to Stack Overflow because it can be answered by professional and enthusiast programmers, as people on WPSE are essentially only aspiring developers.*

Comment: I've added the status-review tag so that we can put this in the backlog. We have a feeling this messaging may affect more than just this site.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention - I agree that this can be confusing and we're working on updating the text for this.